# How to use swift3 xib at ios8?

Tags: ios, swift3

My project use Xib, it canbe load at ios9+ and simulator, but cannot at iOS8.

I try to override init(`nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?`) method, at `swift2.3` it can be resolved, but at `swift3` it fails.

What can I do to make the xib load at ios8?

Comment: i have resloved, i should use method`init(nibName: , bundle: )` to init the viewcontroller rather than`init()`, then at the viewcontroller rewrite `override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "nib_name", bundle: nil)
let popupView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
```

Comment: the xib is associate to the UIViewController, you method cannot be used

Comment: i have resloved, i should use method`init(nibName: , bundle: )` to init the viewcontroller, then at the viewcontroller rewrite `override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?)`. Thank you